Calculate the Length of overlapping vectors within the same Line layer
I have one layer with a bunch of lines (Cables) and in some places there are multiple cables running parallel. I need to find out length for Singe cable, Length for 2 parallel, 3 and so on.
There isn't a way to filter and split this layer into non overlapping types of cables and compare them.
I need something similar to this function in QGIS.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/count-overlapping-features.htm
I ran the same function on ArcGisPro and it doesn't seem to be giving me the result I want. Even though I set the minimum overlap to 1, my resulting layer has vectors that have no other vectors overlapping it.
